# Click on a button with specific text in puppeteer

Tags: html, puppeteer

hello I need a method to click with puppeteer on a button that has an identical class to others but different text inside the problem is that this text is identical to others on the page so in short I need a way to click on a button with a text below a specific class. is there any way? I hope I have explained, thanks

my code at the moment :

```
await page.click ("._0xLoFW.FCIprz")
```

html :

`<div class="_0xLoFW FCIprz"><span class="_7Cm1F9 ka2E9k uMhVZi dgII7d z-oVg8 pVrzNP">40</span></div>`

Answer (score 1):

You can try XPath:

```js
const [element] = await $x("//div[@class='_0xLoFW FCIprz'][.='40']");
await element.click();
```

Comment: Can you or someone explain or give a reference about what the second square bracket does?

Comment: @ImBIOS If you mean `[.='40']`: `.` is the selected node; on comparing to a string, the text content of this node is compared with other argument, i.e. `'40'`.

Comment: @ImBIOS See https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/